# Delete files on cron schedule

Tags: linux, cron, schedule, delete-file

I looked up google on that delete cron -- I have that:

```
17 13 * * * root find /backups/dslcart-* -mtime +6 -exec rm {} \;
```

But it isn't working as it is supposed to delete all older files with dslcart-(date). I am not sure where I could go wrong with this?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: **what is the problem or which does not work?**

Comment: What does "it isn't working" mean?

Comment: (For posterity) try `find /backups -maxdepth 1 -name 'dslcart-*' -mtime +6 -delete`.  I'm not sure why your version was failing, but using `-delete`  is much safer, and your version could fail if the list of files to delete was too large, as it expands the file list on the command line rather than iterating through the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write a shell script or even easier, a Perl Script to act as your liason for the function of deleting those files? This way you have more control over function and output everytime this event fires off. And this allows you test your function without waiting on your cron events. You'll simply call the script from your cron.

Comment: perl script is good idea, but unfortunately, I am not familiar with perl -- can you please point me to the good perl tutorial or something similar?

Comment: Ill do yo one better. Whats the path to the directory we are trying to clean up? Ill post the script here.

Comment: louierd, thanks! The path to the directory is /backups in outside /var/www/. i am trying to delete the files (dslcart-[date]) which is 7 days older.

Comment: Darn, seems like I left you hanging Josephine. Just didn't feel like logging back in since Feb of 2011, now I am back. Anyway, am pretty sure you've figured this one out since it's been a year since you posted this question, if not let me know. My apologies :(

Comment: This is a bad answer. Why is the one line script above inefficient for deleting old files. If it works, who cares what the output is? If you call the script from the cron then the argument for "waiting for your cron" doesn't matter... I'm downvoting.

Comment: @AlxVallejo Who said anything about efficiency?  Security is another story though - the OP's formulation is highly exploitable.  The reason for a proposed perl script though was flexibility and testability, though I'm not sure the reasons for that have been established.

Answer (score 0):

I use this (for my 'amavis' user) to clean up quarantined spam files older than 30 days on my mail server:

0 1 * * * find /var/lib/amavis/virusmails -ctime +30 -and -type 'f' -exec rm {} \;

Comment: additionally, I don't think this wildcard will be expanded: /backups/dslcart-*

Comment: oh that's what I thought. But when I ran the cmd without exec rm, it shows correct paths to the files inside directory...